# Can the Openshift deployment suddenly disappear

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, openshift

Question : Can the deployment done on Openshift or Kubernetes disappear? What I mean is I did a deployment yesterday for one of the applications on Openshift cluster. Its a Java based application. The application has 5 modules. All the 5 modules were present before the deployment. I was upgrading the tomcat version for one of the modules. Now that modules is deployed and present but other 4 modules have suddenly disappeared. My question is what can cause the other deployments to disappear. I cannot share the logs as its handled by other team in my company and we have asked them for the logs and to check what caused this issue.

Comment: this seems more like an openshift issue.

Comment: Ok. Yes we are trying to debug it and get to the root cause. Has anyone faced this kind of issue with Openshift earlier.

Comment: What are the specific logs we can check in Openshift to debug or find the root cause. Can anybody help.